# Python 3.5.1 in Anaconda 3 from JetBrains PyCharm IDE - environment objects

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda

I am coming into Python from R, and installed Python 3.5 with Anaconda. Now, PyCharm console has a prompt identical to an iPython Notebook, i.e. instead of `>>>`, it shows `[1]` at the command line.

After writing a toy line of code (below) in a `.py` document, and running it from within PyCharm, showing no errors, I was under the assumption that the function `toss()`, which was defined in the `.py` document would be ready to use in the console. However this did not seem to be the case. I ended up copying and pasting the pertinent lines of code on the console, entering, and then, finally, the function `toss()` was accessible to produce random examples of the roll of a die.

Logically, there has to be a smoother way of moving code from a `.py` file in the Editor to the environment accessible from the Python Console. But this shorter way doesn't seem to be simply running the `.py` file.

Code:

> import random
>
> def  toss():
>       return(random.randint(1,6))

So how do you make the code in a Python file in the Editor accessible in the local environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import it first. Let's say that your function `toss()` is in a file called `foo.py` then that means that you can do

```
from foo import toss
toss()
```

in your Python Console to use your function.  A Python source file is, by definition, a [module](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/111871/module-vs-package) and you'll need to import it in order to use any functions defined there.

Comment: Thank you, Paul. So "running" the file to make sure there is no error doesn't automatically place the contents of the `.py` file in the "radius" of accessible objects and functions accessible from the console... Can you import `toss()` even before running the file?

Comment: Right, you don't need to run the file first.  You might need to `Rerun` the Python Console (Ctrl-F5) if you have changed any code in the file and you want to do a re-import in the console.  I would recommend looking into using a [jupyter notebook](http://jupyter.org/) -- it's really much more powerful than the Python Console in PyCharm

Comment: Thank you. I'm going to accept your answer, and up-vote. You know, I really don't like Jupyter Notebook at all. There is something about it... It allows using R and Python, markdown and LaTex... It sounds great... But, I feel constrained using it, and without a sense of time-linearity if this makes any sense. I do love RStudio...